# Enable Django format localization by default

Tags: python, django, localization, formatting

This is about the [Format Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization) feature that was implemented in Django 1.2.

In order to use this feature, you must add a `localize=True` parameter to all your form fields. I am trying to implement this localization in my app but the problem is that I am creating my forms dynamically by using the `inlineformset_factory` method that Django provides, so I cannot simply add a new parameter to the form field.

So I tried to enable this feature by default in all models, without needing to add a new parameter for all fields. I created a BaseInlineFormSet subclass and hard-coded the parameter in it.

```
class MyBaseInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyBaseInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            for key, field in form.fields.iteritems():
                if field.__class__ == forms.DecimalField:
                    form.fields[key].localize = True
```

That worked only 50%. When submitted, the forms are being validated correctly by Django now (it's accepting commas instead of only dot) but the fields are still being displayed incorrectly.

I guess I could javascript my way out of this problem, but I prefer to avoid doing that.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django 1.2 is 3 years old now. Django 1.6 provides a nice way to solve your dilemma:

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#enabling-localization-of-fields):

By default, the fields in a ModelForm will not localize their data. To enable localization for fields, you can use the localized_fields attribute on the Meta class.

```
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm
>>> from myapp.models import Author
>>> class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Author
...         localized_fields = ('birth_date',)
```

If localized_fields is set to the special value `__all__`, all fields will be localized

Answer (score 0):

I've have not used it - (still to picka  project to develop in Django) - 
but it seens to be the case of subclassing -

Instead of having your fields inheriting from forms.DecimalField, make them be a:

```
class LocalizedDecimalField(forms.DecimalField):
    localize = True
```